# Remove Redundant row with large number of variable

Tags: r

I have data with 33 attribute. 30 of them is variable. And other 3 column is cluster number ,degree and sum of degree. I want to remove duplicate row which have same value from variable 1 until 30. Within duplicate row I want to choose the row which have highest values of sum degree to remain in the data. This coding is run in `R`. My question is how do I simplify `zz`.

```
df_order=dfOrder(rule2,c(33),ascending=FALSE)
df_order2=as_tibble(df_order)
zz=df_order2 %>% distinct(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,X18,X19,X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,X27,X28,X29,X30,.keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- tibble(a=rep(1:2, each=10), b=rep(1:4, each=5), x1=sample(3,size=20,replace=TRUE), x2=sample(3,size=20,replace=TRUE), x3=sample(3,size=20,replace=TRUE))
dat
# # A tibble: 20 x 5
#        a     b    x1    x2    x3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     1     1     1     3
#  2     1     1     1     3     3
#  3     1     1     1     1     1
#  4     1     1     1     1     1
#  5     1     1     2     2     2
#  6     1     2     2     3     2
# ...truncated...
```

Brute-force to show what `distinct` gives you:

```r
distinct(dat, x1, x2, x3, .keep_all = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 14 x 5
#        a     b    x1    x2    x3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     1     1     1     3
#  2     1     1     1     3     3
#  3     1     1     1     1     1
#  4     1     1     2     2     2
#  5     1     2     2     3     2
#  6     1     2     1     1     2
#  7     1     2     3     2     2
#  8     1     2     3     2     3
#  9     2     3     1     3     2
# 10     2     3     1     3     1
# 11     2     3     2     2     3
# 12     2     4     3     1     2
# 13     2     4     1     2     1
# 14     2     4     3     2     1
```

Programmatic way, without specifying each of `x1` through `x3`, both work (depending on your preference towards "just use these" or "don't use those"). The first two work in base R and tidyverse equally well, the third is using `dplyr::select`.

```r
dat[!duplicated(subset(dat, select = -(a:b))),]
dat[!duplicated(subset(dat, select = x1:x3)),]
dat[!duplicated(select(dat, x1:x3)),]            # or -(a:b), same
```

Or perhaps a pipe-looking method:

```r
select(dat, x1:x3) %>% 
  Negate(duplicated)(.) %>%
  which(.) %>%
  slice(dat, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data from @r2evans post an option is to use splice after converting the column names to symbols

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    distinct(!!! rlang::syms(names(select(., starts_with('x')))), .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 14 x 5
#       a     b    x1    x2    x3
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     3
# 2     1     1     1     3     3
# 3     1     1     1     1     1
# 4     1     1     2     2     2
# 5     1     2     2     3     2
# 6     1     2     1     1     2
# 7     1     2     3     2     2
# 8     1     2     3     2     3
# 9     2     3     1     3     2
#10     2     3     1     3     1
#11     2     3     2     2     3
#12     2     4     3     1     2
#13     2     4     1     2     1
#14     2     4     3     2     1
```

---

From `dplyr` version `>= 1.0.0`, we can also use `distinct` with `across`

```
dat %>%
    distinct(across(starts_with('x')), .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 14 x 5
#       a     b    x1    x2    x3
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     3
# 2     1     1     1     3     3
# 3     1     1     1     1     1
# 4     1     1     2     2     2
# 5     1     2     2     3     2
# 6     1     2     1     1     2
# 7     1     2     3     2     2
# 8     1     2     3     2     3
# 9     2     3     1     3     2
#10     2     3     1     3     1
#11     2     3     2     2     3
#12     2     4     3     1     2
#13     2     4     1     2     1
#14     2     4     3     2     1
```